# How to wait for a process that outputs a line that matches a pattern in Java?

Tags: java, process

I'm using `ProcessBuilder` in Java to run a process. I want my program to wait for the `Process` until it output stream has a line that matches a given pattern, or until a time limit exceeds.

I use `BufferedReader` to read line by line from `Process.getOutputStream` while matching each line to the pattern. It worked fine when there is a match or the process terminated before any match. But when the process doesn't output anymore line after a give time limit, the `BufferedReader.readLine()` block and the thread reading from `Process.getOutputStream` never completes.

Here is my code.

```
private static Timer setTimeout(Runnable runnable, long timeoutMillis) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runnable.run();
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }, timeoutMillis);
    return timer;
}

static CompletableFuture<Process> startProcessAndWaitForMatchedOutput(
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder, String pattern, long waitForMillis) {
    final CompletableFuture<Process> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();

    final Process process;
    try {
        process = processBuilder.start();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        completableFuture.completeExceptionally(ex);
        return completableFuture;
    }

    final Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    final Timer timeoutTimer = setTimeout(() -> 
        completableFuture.completeExceptionally(new WaitForTimeExceededException()),
        waitForMillis);

    new Thread(() -> {
        try (InputStream processOutputStream = process.getInputStream();
             InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(processOutputStream);
             BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {

            String line;
            /* The thread is blocked here. 
            Indeed the code call this method always return because 
            my completableFuture always completes. 
            But the problem is there is a running thread 
            which is a waste of resource. */
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (compiledPattern.matcher(line).matches()) {
                    completableFuture.complete(process);
                    timeoutTimer.cancel();
                    return;
                }
            }

            completableFuture.completeExceptionally(new OutputDidNotMatchException());
            timeoutTimer.cancel();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            completableFuture.completeExceptionally(ex);
            timeoutTimer.cancel();
        }
    }).start();

    return completableFuture;
}
```

Is my solution correct? If not, is there some libraries that solve my problem?

Comment: If the process takes too long you can kill it, stopping the process and closing the output stream.

Comment: I don't want to kill the process when there is no matched output. I want the thread that reading process's output to returns.

Comment: In that case, close the InputStream from another thread.